# To get a strong convergent subsequence in $L^p_{loc}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is a smooth bounded domain and $1<,p<\infty.$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Please help me regarding this question:
Let $1<p<\infty$ and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a smooth bounded domain.
Given a uniformly bounded sequence in $W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$. Then upto a subsequence 
$
u_n\to u\,\,weakly\,\,in\,\,W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)
$

$
u_n\to u\,\,strongly\,\,in\,\,L^p_{loc}(\Omega)
$
and
$
u_n\to u\,\,a.e.\,\,in\,\,\Omega.
$
If this is true , can You give a clear explanation how to prove it?\
Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\subset\Omega$ is a smooth subset of $\Omega$ with $\overline{A}\subset\Omega$, the injection from $W^{1,p}(A)$ to $L^p(A)$ is compact (by the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem).

You can construct a sequence $(A_j)$ of smooth domains invading $\Omega$.
Since $(u_n)$ is bounded in $W^{1,p}(A_j)$, you can extract a subsequence strongly convergent in $L^p(A_j)$ (and also pointwise a.e.).
Moreover, up to another subsequence, you have also weak convergence in $W^{1,p}(A_j)$ (since $1<p<\infty$).

Using a diagonal argument, you can construct a subsequence of $(u_n)$ that 
weakly converges in $W^{1,p}(A_j)$ adn strongly converges in $L^p(A_j)$ for every $j$ (and pointwise a.e. on $\bigcup_j A_j = \Omega$).

Comment: Thank you very much for giving your precious time to explain the answer. I have a small doubt in the answer. To prove the weak convergence or strong convergence in $W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$, we need to prove that for every relatively compact subset $A$(need not be smooth) of $\Omega$ such that $\overline{A}\Omega$ we have $u_n$ converges to $u$ weakly in $W^{1,p}(A)$. But in the argument it is proved for any such $A$ which is smooth. Can you please explain why it is enough to prove only for smooth $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving your precious time to explain the answer. I have a small doubt in the answer. To prove the weak convergence or strong convergence in $W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$, we need to prove that for every relatively compact subset $A$(need not be smooth) of $\Omega$ such that $\overline{A}\subset\Omega$ we have $u_n$ converges to $u$ weakly in $W^{1,p}(A)$. But in the argument it is proved for any such $A$ which is smooth. Can you please explain why it is enough to prove only for smooth $A$.

Comment: Since the sequence $(A_j)$ is invading $\Omega$, i.e. $A_1\subset A_2\subset\cdots$ and $\bigcup_j A_j = \Omega$, then every compact set $K\subset\Omega$ is contained in some $A_j$.

Comment: Please verify if what I understoodd is correct or not.

Comment: Please verify if what I understood is correct or not. For smooth bounded domain $\Omega$ by $u_n$ converges to $u$ weakly in $W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$, we mean $u_n$ converges to $u$ weakly in $W^{1,p}(A)$ for every $A$ smooth subset of $\Omega$ such that $\overline{A}\subset\Omega$ (due to the exhaustion of $\Omega$  by smooth  sets $A_j$ such that $\overline{A_j}\subset\Omega$). I think the same definition is valid for $L^p_{loc}(\Omega)$. And a last question can you tell me how the exhaustion property of smooth $\Omega$ by smooth sets $A_j$ holds. Thanks

Comment: By convergence in $W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$ we mean the convergence in $W^{1,p}(A)$ for every open $A$ with compact closure contained in $\Omega$. For every such $A$ we can find $j$ such that $A\subset A_j$, hence the convergence in $W^{1,p}(A)$ is induced by the convergence in $W^{1,p}(A_j)$.

Comment: To prove the strong convergence in $L^p_{loc}(\Omega)$ to apply Rellich compactness theorem, I think you are using the argument: $u_n$ converges to $u$ weakly in $W^{1,p}(K)$ implies $u_n$ converges to $u$ weakly in $W^{1,p}(A_j)$ where $K\subset A_j$ for some $j$. Please help me to get this argument. Thanks.

Comment: It's the opposite. Since $(u_n)$ converges weakly in $W^{1,p}(A_j)$, then $(u_n)$ converges strongly in $L^p(A_j)$, hence converges strongly in $L^p(K)$ (if $K\subset A_j$).

Comment: Sorry Sir, I have got the argument now. In particular $A_j$ is relatively compact the using Rellich compactness theorem we can prove the result.Thank you very very much for your kind help.

Comment: Can you give me some reference where can I get the exhaustion of smooth $\Omega$  by  smooth $A_j$ as written by You.

Comment: Since your $\Omega$ is bounded and smooth, you can simply choose $A_j = \{x\in \Omega:\ dist(x, \partial\Omega) > 1/j\}$. This set is smooth for $j$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Thank You very much Sir.